# regarding web scraping - using urllib (maybe also beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

Website I'm scraping from: [link](http://mansci.journal.informs.org/gca?gca=mansci;6/2/141&gca=mansci;6/2/149&gca=mansci;6/2/165&gca=mansci;6/2/172&gca=mansci;6/2/187&gca=mansci;6/2/191&gca=mansci;6/2/197&gca=mansci;6/2/205&gca=mansci;6/2/215&submit=Get%20All%20Checked%20Abstracts)

The tags I want to parse between: START - `<p id="p-1">`, FINISH - `</p>`

My code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen('http://mansci.journal.informs.org/gca?gca=mansci%3B6%2F2%2F141&gca=mansci%3B6%2F2%2F149&gca=mansci%3B6%2F2%2F165&gca=mansci%3B6%2F2%2F172&gca=mansci%3B6%2F2%2F187&gca=mansci%3B6%2F2%2F191&gca=mansci%3B6%2F2%2F197&gca=mansci%3B6%2F2%2F205&gca=mansci%3B6%2F2%2F215&submit=Get+All+Checked+Abstracts').read()

a = re.compile('<p id="p-1">(.*)</p>')
b = re.findall(a,html)
```

The problem I'm having is that my code looks line by line, I dont know how to parse the entire paragraph.

Comment: I have fixed the formatting, and removed the note regarding spacing.

Comment: thanks! first time on this website. just learning how to code!

Answer (score 0):

Using beautifulsoup, then the following:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(your_url).read())
print soup.find('p', {'id': 'p-1'}).text
```

Gives...

> The possibility of measuring does not necessarily lead to the
>   presentation of relevant information for decision-making in
>                              business. This is demonstrated by reference to accounting methods and to profit computation in particular.
>   Accounting processes
>                              have become formalized to the point where they misrepresent financial results and position; the probability that
>   resources
>                              will be used efficiently and that equity between parties of interest will be served is materially reduced by
>   lack of care
>                              in the definition of significant concepts and the concurrent acceptance of procedures which have directly
>   opposite justifications
>                              and consequences. As the speed of information processing increases and computational refinements
>   develop, a corresponding
>                              effort is necessary to redefine in operationally relevant terms, or to sharpen the definition of, such
>   key concepts as profit,
>                              capital, cost. The history of the development of accounting and auxiliary calculations illustrates the
>   consequences of permitting
>                              a measuring and communicating system to become institutionalized. Some suggestions for improving the relevance
>   of accounting
>                              and similar information are made.

Comment: Very Helpful. I'll see what i can do from here